# Deploying Node\Express app to production - is it just copying?

Tags: node.js, express

this is first time Im doing this, so I have to wonder:

Does "deploying to production", when it comes to a Node JS app - simply means copying the .js files to production? there's no 'build' operation or anything like that? and what about sensitive information, like usernames, password, etc? on dev its in an ENV file. Do I just move it to prod? somehow I think I missed something big...

Thank You!

Comment: effectively yes, but, there's many things you can do to automate/improve the process to prevent problems and avoid exposing secure information... but... ultimately they're all moving code from A to B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the comment of Kevin B is correct. The Javascript code doesn't need to compile or build so this step does not exist.

We could have, however, a test phase before deploying to production. Or, if you are using Typescript, a "build" phase to compile the code to Javascript.

For the environment variable, you're correct.

Answer (score -1):

It depends on what / how you make, but generally, you can move your app to production by sending a copy of your application's code to some server. There are different options for how you manage your code and how you send and manage production code. Basically, you can use `git` as version control, and use `heroku` platform to host your production server, the way you do that is, for sensitive data like tokens, secrets, username and etc, you should manage that stuff through *Environment Variables*. So when you moved your application to production, you can set credentials, secrets and etc using some interface on the server, in the case of `heroku` you can use Heroku dashboard of your app, to set things like production url of your database and any other stuff.